# Searching User In Active Directory By Full Name

Tags: search, vbscript, active-directory

I'm looking for the way to search users in Active Directory using VBScript. I can search by username or any Active Directory using ADODB Connection:

```
Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
objConnection.Provider = ("ADsDSOObject")
objConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"
objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection
objCommand.Properties("SearchScope") = 2
objCommand.CommandText = "SELECT userWorkstations,sAMAccountName,Mail,name,DisplayName,distinguishedName FROM 'LDAP://dc=NESTLE,dc=com' WHERE objectCategory='user' AND name='" & VaR5 & "'"
Set objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute
```

But I'd like to find a user with his full name, for example "John Doe" (User:Jdoe). So like in the *AD Users and Computers* interface we could search by "John Doe".

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
"... name='" & var5 & "'"
```

to either

```
"... displayName='" & var5 & "'"
```

or

```
"... sn='" & lastname & "' and givenName='" & firstname & "'"
```

For the latter you need 2 variables: one with the first and the other with the last name.

Comment: great idea but i have another problem, because initialy my variable is "John doe" that i could separate with split, OK, but with a name like "TI TU PHAN Nguyen" it would not work, i need in fact to use the same function used in AD interface for searching, you can use name, first name, full name , mail or UserID. i think if it's possible i will test with resolve function in outlook. wait and see
thanks for Answer...

Comment: I can't test this right now, but you should be able to combine the various conditions with `or` operators: `name='...' or (sn='...' and givenName='...') or displayName='...' or mail='...' or ...`

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems to work by workaround Using Outlook Function

`Dim myOlApp`

`Dim myOlNameSpace`

`Dim objFolder`

`Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")`

`Set myOlNameSpace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")`

`Set myRecipient = myOlNameSpace.CreateRecipient("Martin Pierre-François")`

`myRecipient.Resolve`

`msgbox myRecipient`

And after I do my search in AD with displayName Attribute

Thanks For All